# How can I request a feature in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

I haven't found any (e.g.) bug database besides http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/, and I think they want me to ask here first.  So: here's a feature I want; to whom should I tell it?

I'd like to be able to associate some text with a star on Google Maps -- so that I can note *why* I bothered to star a place.  (Typical reasons are: I read a great review of this restaurant, and here's it's URL; this is the hotel we stayed at last time; etc).  I have lots of stars and often forget why I starred them.

I realize that I could accomplish this by creating my own map, and adding the places to it; but using "my maps" is awkward and tedious; I'd like this information to be in my face all the time.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't the place to report enhancement requests to Google. Use the "Report a Problem" feature in the lower-right corner of [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com). Under "All Other Problems", you'll find "All other comments, feedback on Google Maps". [The link](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues) you posted in your question is the other way.

Comment: Aha, thanks! I'd looked briefly at the "Report a Problem" feature, but it seemed to be only for reporting incorrect map data; I never explored the "All Other Problems" link.

Answer (score 2):

Posting my comment as an answer so this one can be closed out:

StackOverflow isn't the place to report enhancement requests to Google. Use the "Report a Problem" feature in the lower-right corner of Google Maps. Under "All Other Problems", you'll find "All other comments, feedback on Google Maps". The link you posted in your question is the other way.

Answer (score 0):

As Gady P. commented: Use the "Report a Problem" feature in the lower-right corner of Google Maps. Under "All Other Problems", you'll find "All other comments, feedback on Google Maps". The link you posted in your question is the other way.